# Android studio cant override view layout not found?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I am trying to override my view but Android studio can't seem to find my fragment_master XML file.
Please help...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clean and rebuild your project..
And also add return view(onCreateView) in your MasterFragment Class

Comment: Your welcome... If my answer solve your problem kindly mark it.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to add `return view;`

try below code :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_master, container, false);

        return view;
    }
```

Now `Clean` and `Rebuild` your project

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported the proper `R.java` file

```
     import sg.edu.nyp.assignment1.R;
```